# can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to resolve this error;

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
```

Where i'm wanting to merge two dataframes created by with `agg` as;

First i created a df of grouped data from main df;

```
resi_all_nooutliers_bysector = df_resi_rawdata_nooutliers.groupby(['postcode_sector'])

resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector = df_resi_rawdata_nooutliers.loc[df_resi_rawdata_nooutliers['propertytype']=='F'].groupby(['postcode_sector'])
```

Then i ran the stats i wanted

```
resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector['updatedprice_calculated'].
agg([np.mean,np.median,np.max,'count'])

resi_all_nooutliers_bysector['updatedprice_calculated'].
agg([np.mean,np.median,np.max,'count'])
```

Then i tried to merge as;

```
df_resi_nooutliers_bysector = pd.merge(resi_all_nooutliers_bysector, 
                                       resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector,
                                       on=['postcode_sector'],how='left', 
                                       suffixes=('_allprop', '_flats'))
```

Getting the error in title

Comment: the gap between `resi_all_nouutliers_bysector`to `resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector`is missing. Concerning the error regarding `reset_index`: Try to call it without argument.

Comment: Have edited but there is a gap, and still get same issue

Comment: So essential information are still laging. Could you provide samplke data (in particular also w.r.t columns ( columns for each frame suffice). This might help people solve your question and understand the error, which by the way is pretty clear: you can't join a grouped object with a non grouped dataframe. However, if you just apply a function to your group, it becomes a dataframe again and joinign is possible!

Comment: Have added the table , any help hugely appreciatated, new to python

Comment: `resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector`is not defined! Your question is not well defined. In you last step you probably need to join on index in left table and 'postcode_sector' in right table. Please provide a clear short description of you problem, provide a small glimpse of the raw data, show what you have tried and provide you expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, have edited and resolved

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked, saving the agg output into an dataframe, ensuring index was on original index (column `postcode_sectors`)

```
df1 = resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector['updatedprice_calculated'].\
agg([np.mean,np.median,np.max,'count'],as_index=False)

df2 = resi_all_nooutliers_bysector['updatedprice_calculated'].\
agg([np.mean,np.median,np.max,'count'],as_index=False)
type (resi_flats_nooutliers_bysector)
df1.head(10)
```

Then use the index for join

```
merge_test = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True,suffixes=
('_allprop', '_flats'))
merge_test.head(10)`
```

Comment: Nice, reducing the problem often helps :) Glad you found an answer on your own.